# xaml listview how to disable space for scroll?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I working on a metro app and I am using listview 
listview automatically puts some space on right side for scroll. In my code there is no need for scrolling
I tried to disable it ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" or scrollmode=false but the space allways appears

is there a way I could disappear it because listview highlights on over and click mode and it looks bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a copy of the current ListView Style by selecting Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item Container -> Edit a Copy (see screenshot below).

In the template copy, modify the Margin (last line shown below)

```
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,18,2"/>
```

to

```
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
```

You'll also need to set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"` on the ListView itself (like you tried before(, or you can get adventurous and modify the template for the ListView itself (Edit Template) and remove the `ScrollViewer` and set the `ItemsPanelTemplate` to just `StackPanel` from `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

[image]